# custom background image for each radio button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to have radio buttons using buttonset (if there is another option other than buttonset, happy to entertain it, but I just assume you have to use it) that have an icon background, unique icon to each button.

I want it to:

1. Have no radio button icon
2. Have a rollover effect
3. Have an icon as background
4. Have a different style for when checked and hovered

The current code I have is

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="new_sort_options">
   <input type="radio" name="new_sort" id="sort_az" /><label for="sort_az">A-Z</label>  
   <input type="radio" name="new_sort" id="sort_popular" /><label for="sort_popular">Popular</label>
 </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $( "#new_results_sort" ).buttonset();
```

**CSS**

```
#new_sort_options .ui-button {
    background-color:#FFFFFF; 
    background-image:url('../images/mpg2.png'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    border-radius:4px; 
    margin:0; 
}
```

Now when I place this background image in the css it works, but it is the same background image for all of the radio buttons. I tried making a separate id for each of them, and making a background image for each, but it didn't make any difference.

Anyone know how to create custom background images for each radio button

Comment: Don't try to play with inputs my friends! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256992/radio-button-background-image

Comment: Just a suggestion. For multi-line code, indent them by 4 spaces (or) use the `{}` button in the button bar for formatting it as code block.

Comment: Use id marking for the different buttons you want to style

Answer (score 1):

Example of CSS that works: http://jsfiddle.net/dmdBh/1/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="group"/>
<label for="radio1"></label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="group"/>
<label for="radio2"></label>
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type="radio"]{
    display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label
{
    background: #999;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label
{
    background: #0080FF;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about inline css

```
<label  style="background-image:url('./images/mpg2.png');" for="sort_az">A-Z</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

my solution: use other dom element instead, write your own radio behavior javascript.
something like this

`html

```
<div class="opts pdtb">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="radio" data-id="F">option1</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="radio" data-id="N">option2</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="radio" data-id="S">option3</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="type" class="fb-type" value="" />
</div>
```

javascript

```
$('.radio').click(function() {

        var t = $(this)
        t.addClass('radio-on').siblings().removeClass('radio-on')
        t.siblings('input').val(t.data('id'))

    )}
```

Comment: sorry, what is behaviour javascript?