# css background to radio button

Tags: css, html, background

I am trying to set background color to radio button with instead of using an image. I tried with checkbox and it worked. Can I try similar code for radio button also which work in all browsers? Like adding div with curves on all ends is just an idea. Please suggest [My fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/sXZuW/86/)

```
<div style="width:10px;height:10px;" class="unchkd">
</div>Test1
<div style="width:10px;height:10px;" class="unchkd">
</div>Test2

$('div').on('click',function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('unchkd')){
        $(this).removeClass('unchkd').addClass('chkd');
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('chkd').addClass('unchkd');
    }
});
.chkd{
    background-color:blue
}
.unchkd{
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid black
}
```

Comment: I believe this is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256992/radio-button-background-image

Comment: This experience looks like a checkbox. I am trying to get radio button experience.

Comment: Yes, it's hacking a checkbox to make it appear as a radio button because it can't be done literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but instead of `div` use `label` and hide the radio by setting it's opacity to zero.

Markup something like:

```
<label for="male">
    <input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />
    <span class="radio"></span>
    Male
</label>

<label for="female">
    <input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />
    <span class="radio"></span>
    Female
</label>
```

And then the CSS:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

input[type="radio"] + .radio {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + .radio {
    background: #333;
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sXZuW/89/).

Comment: I am struggling and did not work for me by changing to label. If you have couple of mins, could you please update my fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

you can use existing script for that example:
http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/ or http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/